# Doctrine 2 flushes the wrong entity first

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have this database design and in some instances Doctrine 2 makes the correct decisions in insert order and sometimes not

[image]

I have an automated import process that imports and updates data as the data provider changes it. The field item.something_happened_item_history_id is the new field that causes issues

When starting the import

Step 1. No data in the database and I create one item and one item_history, where item_history.item_id is the item.id and item.something_happened_item_history_id is null. Now I do Flush and Doctrine can figure it out that it needs to insert item before item_history. All is good.

Step 2. Now a new import comes in, and some of the data already exists in the database from the Step 1. But in the new import I actually have a new unique item. So what I do is that I create the item and item_history exactly as in Step 1. But for some reason during the Flush Doctrine thinks that item_history needs to be saved before the item. Which can't be done, because of not nullable foreign key reference on item_history.

I understand that Doctrine makes decisions based on foreign key references and the field something_happened_item_history_id is causing trouble. But it doesn't cause any trouble in the step 1. The problems occur when there is already some data in the database that is loaded into the entityManager.

I haven't been able to figure out how to manipulate Doctrine 2 so that it would always save the item before item_history.

Any ideas how to solve it?

As I really do not want to change my database design, because Doctrine 2 can't figure out the insert order.

Also it is not an option to do more Flushes, as there is a lot of data validation done before the data goes to the database. And I do not want any corrupt data in the database.

Best Regards,
Hendrik

**EDIT: Doctrine 2 mapping**

```
/**
 * @Table(name="item", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(name="uc_something_happened_item_history", columns={"something_happened_item_history_id"})})
 **/
class Item
{
    /** @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true}) @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="ItemHistory", mappedBy="item")
     **/
    protected $itemHistories;


    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ItemHistory")
     * @JoinColumn(name="something_happened_item_history_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, unique=true)
     **/
    protected $somethingHappenedItemHistory;
}

/**
 * @Table(name="item_history")
 **/
class ItemHistory
{
    /** @Id @Column(name="id", type="integer", options={"unsigned":true}) @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="itemHistories")
     * @JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     **/
    protected $item;
}
```

Comment: Are you positive that step 2 for new items is exactly the same code as step 1?  It sounds like $item->setHistory($history) is never being called so the objects are not cross linked.  Doctrine really should not have a problem with 1:1 bidirectional relations as long as each object points to the other.

Comment: Okay I see the problem now.  Review here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional You need to declare one side to be the owning side.  So now I am a little bit skeptical that your step 1 is actually working.

Comment: Hi Cerad, thanks for replying. I have attached the Doctrine 2 mapping, I have, to the main post. I removed all the other noise from the classes. Hope it helps you to see something I can't. I do not see what I should do more to make one side more owning. They are just referencing each other back and forth. Even, if the code did something else, then Doctrine should be able to figure out that Item needs to go to the database before ItemHistory. Especially, because during the Flush the $somethingHappenedItemHistory is null.

Comment: I confess my uml reading skills are not what they should be.  I did not realize you had two relations.  Still does not make any sense that merely adding the something happened relation would cause a failure only when the database already has data.  It might be the unique constraint.  What database are you using?  mysql ignores null values when checking for a unique constraint.  But most databases don't.  Might even try dropping the constraint.

Comment: I'm using MySql. But as the issue is happening in the Doctrine insert order, then I doubt that the error has anything to do with MySql. Dropping the constraint would work, but that is my very last option to solve the problem :).

Comment: So what makes you think it is an insert order problem?  Can you post any error messages?

Comment: I xdebugged into the Doctrine unitOfWork, before it starts inserting data into the database. I can see in that insert list for step 1, the item comes before the item_history and in step 2 the item_history comes before the item.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't resolved the problem the way I wanted.

But by making the item_id nullable, then the Doctrine is able to finish the flush.
Data is also correct in the database.